# How to get Tomcat 7 to run on Port 80 on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat7, windows-server-2008

I've spent two days trying to get this to work.

When I first started up `Tomcat 7`, it ran on port `8080` which is the Tomcat default. And so it could be accessed but typing: `http://localhost:8080/` or `mydomain.com:8080`.

But I wish to move from port `8080` to port `80` so I can type `mydomain.com` and be directed to the web page.

I've disabled all extra services that could be running on port `80` like IIS, MSSQL, World Wide Web Publishing, etc.

In the `server.xml` file, I've made the following change:

`<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />`

And then when I start up the server, I get this in the logs (although the server starts up):

```
...
Dec 27, 2014 9:34:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-80"]
java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:453)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:646)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:821)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)

Dec 27, 2014 9:34:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:821)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:453)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:646)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    ... 13 more

Dec 27, 2014 9:34:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Dec 27, 2014 9:34:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 3310 ms
Dec 27, 2014 9:34:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 27, 2014 9:34:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
Dec 27, 2014 9:34:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Apache\tomcat\webapps\docs
Dec 27, 2014 9:34:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Apache\tomcat\webapps\docs has finished in 1,985 ms
Dec 27, 2014 9:34:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Apache\tomcat\webapps\examples
Dec 27, 2014 9:34:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Apache\tomcat\webapps\examples has finished in 1,234 ms
Dec 27, 2014 9:34:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Apache\tomcat\webapps\host-manager
Dec 27, 2014 9:34:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Apache\tomcat\webapps\host-manager has finished in 453 ms
Dec 27, 2014 9:34:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Apache\tomcat\webapps\manager
Dec 27, 2014 9:34:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Apache\tomcat\webapps\manager has finished in 313 ms
Dec 27, 2014 9:34:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Apache\tomcat\webapps\ROOT
Dec 27, 2014 9:34:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Apache\tomcat\webapps\ROOT has finished in 156 ms
Dec 27, 2014 9:34:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Dec 27, 2014 9:34:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4282 ms
```

and nothing is visible when I access the url `mydomain.com`

I'm incredibly new at this - have gone thru a lot of posts online and followed instructions but nothing seems to work. I'd done the same steps earlier and it had worked like a charm.

What must I do now? Please help.

This is what I got on a `netstat`

[image: netstat result]

Comment: double click Tomcat server and then switch Server Locations to User Tomcat installation http://i.stack.imgur.com/3eDSs.png

Comment: I'm not using Eclipse.

Comment: beside the console in eclipse you will find Servers just double click Tomcate V7..... and then you will see this window http://i.stack.imgur.com/3eDSs.png

Comment: But I'm not using Eclipse..

Comment: what are you using ?

Comment: Nothing. I have downloaded the zip file from the Apache site and installed the service. I'm running it on a Server and do not wish to use Eclipse ...unless it's the last resort

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67782/discussion-between-saturnian-and-ze-rubues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some other app is using port 80. Do a local port scan and print executable path with netstart (This video will help : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=V3nWkr7v4-E#t=7)

Often its skype (or other chat or peer to peer file sharing app). Shutdown skype (quit not just sign out, process should exit) then start tomcat. Then can restart skype it will work fine on some other ports.

Also is there any firewall entry stopping Java from binding to this port? Can check that from your firewall rules - if your using default windows firewall that will be there in Control panel. https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=widows+firewall+java+allow these results or same terms in regular search engine will tell you steps to allow Java. Usually windows asks the first time you run an app. So if you said no then it remembers that. Also will need to have administrator role (logged in/ or on prompt user) to make these changes. For some issues helps to open admin console too. right click on cmd.exe and choose run as administrator, say yes to the security prompt.

This program might help, save it to a file called "PortCheck.java"

```
    class PortCheck{
    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception{
        String port = "80";
        if(args.length > 0)port = args[0];
        final int p = Integer.parseInt(port);
        Thread t = new Thread(){
            public void run(){

                try{
                    java.net.ServerSocket s = new java.net.ServerSocket(p);
                    System.out.println("\nListening on port " + p);
                    s.accept();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Err " + e);
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("Bye ");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Compile it

> javac  c:\_your_path\PortCheck.java

and run it :

> java -cp c:\_your_path  PortCheck

If it succeeds to bind to 80 will tell you :

> Listening on port 80
>   Bye

Can try with port 443 too simiarly

Comment: I'm not running it on my local machine. I'm trying to run it on a Microsoft Server 2008. So no Skype. I've done everything that you've mentioned. No extra services are running on Port 80. Just the TCP is listening in.

Comment: Which TCP and on what port? Did you check the fire wall rules? Is port 80 free?

Comment: I checked for port 80 - It just says TCP in is a LISTENING state. It's foreign address is stating my domain name - I'm assuming that it means that port 80's free?

Comment: I've checked the firewall rules as well, and have followed everything that's shown in those videos. I still can't figure out what's wrong

Comment: I dont understand your earlier comment ' port 80 - It just says TCP in is a LISTENING state' that means some other process is usung your local port 80? Anyway try the code above with java if you have jdk - need that to compile it wth javac c:\yourpathpath\PortCheck.java

Comment: Let me see if I can upload a screenshot to convey my point clearly, meanwhile I'll just check out your code!

Comment: I've added a picture to show you what I was trying to convey

Comment: okay, I don't know HOW it worked but this is what I did:

1) `netstat -p TCP -ao` in the command prompt

2) `taskkill /F /PID 4220`(the PID of the process that occupied port 80)

3) `service.bat uninstall` to uninstall Tomcat7

4) `service.bat install` to re-install Tomcat7

And somehow, this worked! After at least repeating this 4 times!

Thanks a million, @tgkprog !

Comment: Glad it worked out, had to be an other process from the description.